# PHP echo error - same echoes, few work, few doesn't

Tags: php, echo

I have a really weird problem: Below in the code listed 4 echo's are pretty much the same, but only the last ones work properly (First two echoes only print the answer of addition/ subtraction, no text).
Here's the code:

```
    <html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?><br>

<?php $sk1 = $_POST["sk1"];
$sk2 = $_POST["sk2"];
$veiksm = $_POST["veiksmas"];

switch($veiksm){
    default:
        echo "Jus nepasirinkote veiksmo";
        break;

    case "sud":
        echo "Sudeties veiksmo rezultatas: " .$sk1 + $sk2;
        break;

    case "ati":
        echo "Atimties veiksmo rezultatas: " .$sk1 - $sk2;
        break;

    case "dal":
        echo "Dalybos veiksmo rezultatas: " .$sk1 / $sk2;
        break;

    case "dau":
        echo "Daugybos veiksmo rezultatas: " .$sk1 * $sk2;
        break;
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: BTW: If you didn't already saw it you can take a tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see how the site works!

Comment: first question, 4 upvote. Has already figured that out :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put brackets around your calculation like:

```
echo "Atimties veiksmo rezultatas: " . ($sk1 - $sk2);
                                     //^ See here  ^
```

Otherwise you can imagine your echo statement like this:

```
"Sudeties veiksmo rezultatas: 17" + 5 // Same as 0 + 5, because the string is casted to int which is 0
```

Also `*` and `/` works because they are getting evaluated first

Comment: curiosity : why does this happen?

Comment: @SimoneNigro: Because of [Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) – `+ - .` all have the same precedence, and are evaluated from left to right.

Comment: @CBroe the string is lost due to the casting for numerical operation?

Comment: Yes, `Sudeties veiksmo rezultatas: 17` is converted to a numeric value (so that other stuff can be added to it, and that results in 0.

Comment: @SimoneNigro yes! It is searching for a number in the string from left to right! So try this: `echo (int)"Sudeties veiksmo rezultatas: 17" ;` you will get 0, but this `echo (int)"17Sudeties veiksmo rezultatas: 17" ;` will get 17

Answer (score 1):

Put parentheses around the calculation, like this:

```
echo "Sudeties veiksmo rezultatas: " . ($sk1 + $sk2);
```

The reason for this is the order in which the expression is processed. Without parentheses, PHP evaluates everything from left to right, so it will first concatinate `$sk1` to the string. The combined value will be `"Sudeties veiksmo rezultatas: 1"` (if $sk1 is 1).

After that, `$sk2` is added to that value. Because PHP cannot add up a string, it tries to convert it to a number. This conversion fails, because the string starts with a non-numeric text, and defaults to `0` which is added to the value of `$sk2`.

Multiplication and division operators have higher precedence, so they are evaluated first, overriding the left-to-right order. That's why it works for the last two cases.